# How do I store a variable's value in a list instead of a reference?

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

```
a = ['a']
b = ['b']
c = a
ab = [a,b]

print(c)
print(ab)

a[0] = 'c'

print(c)
print(ab)
```

Returns:

```
['a']              
[['a'], ['b']]
['c']
[['c'], ['b']]
```

I wanted the c list to remain what it was i.e. ['a']. But it changed after I changed the element in the a list. Why does this happen and how, if at all, can I avoid it.

Comment: This looks like Python. If so, store a copy of the `a` list in `c` instead of a reference: `c = a[:]`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot to specify that it was python! This worked great alek, I wasn't familiar with the distinction.

Comment: for various options on copying/cloning lists see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/2530083

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the list `a` and assign it to `c`. Right now you are just assigning the reference to `a` to `c`, which is why when you modify `a` you also modify `c`. There are multiple ways to copy `a`, I think the easiest to read uses the list constructor:

```
c = list(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alek's or mtitan8's solutions are probably the most convenient.  To be very explicit, you can `import copy` and then use `c = copy.copy(a)`